# How to calculate an Illumination raster for fire ignition danger analysis?

Tags: dem, hillshade

I am doing a fire ignition danger analysis using this equation that I found in Millington (2012) http://www.jmecology.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/33-42-MILLINGTON.pdf

`IR = 4H + 3V + 2I – E`

Where:

```
H = human presence (i.e. within 30m of a road/trails)
V = vegetation
I = Illumination
E = Elevation
```

It is based in another paper by Salas and Chuvieco (1994) that I couldn't find. My problem is the illumination raster. I found another link where they give some guidelines in how to create it, but I have not found any other reference. http://ibis.geog.ubc.ca/courses/geob370/students/class06/fire/mce.html

Do you know where can I find information related to how to create this raster?

Comment: Welcome to GS@SE. You are more likely to get a useful answer if you specify what software you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1, but I am open to use any other software especially if it's open source.

Comment: The second link you provide walks through the illumination raster process pretty thoroughly. Can you be more specific in your question: do you need to know what tools to use for a particular step? are you unsure how to calculate the solar altitude and azimuth?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to find a more solid reference, which shows for example the criteria in what day to use (I think it should be the hottest summer day) and more theory about it. I think the procedure is well explained, just need to use the Hillshade tool and the raster calculator. I have looked for innformation and I haven´t found any other reference about how to create an illumination raster. By the way, it seems that GRASS GIS has a function, (r.sun) but I am not sure if it is the same procedure that it is explained in the second link.

Comment: Update: I have found that "illumination" is used as a synonym of "insolation" and this as a synonym of radiation. ArcGIS has a Solar Analyst extension for the creation of radiation maps. I am still not sure if it's the same, but I will try to find more information.

Comment: @Ernesto561 I would think that the Solar Analyst will provide the exact illumination data that you are looking for. Why don't you provide an answer to your own question?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Solar Analyst did the job, I forgot to update this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the Solar Analyst extension for ArcGIS can create radiation maps, which is a synonim for the illumination map I was looking for.